# Determining server-type from http request

Tags: c++, httpserver

I have a web-server written in CPP. I want to determine the server-type of the request. i.e whether the request came from http or https URL ?

Comment: You can't really handle `http` and `https` on the same network port, as `https` requires an encrypted connection.

Comment: the http:// or https:// defines the PROTOCOL being used for the request, not the server-type...

Comment: Can't you find out from the actual server code? What server code are you using - it might pass through some extra data you can check for about the secured request if it's HTTPS.

Comment: Or is this all behind a firewall that's redirecting both sets of traffic to the same internal point? If so you'll have to hope your firewall has added data to the request header.

Answer (score 4):

If you have your own web-server written in c++ you already know whether it came over http or https as they come through different ports and require different handling.

Comment: the problem is both HTTP and HTTP server are listening on same port i.e both VIPS are pointing to same port ?

Comment: A "virtual IP" is _not_ a port. TCP/IP uses IP addresses to identify a particular (virtual) machine, and TCP port numbers to identify a service on that machine.

Comment: A virtual IP address is distinct from the port. You normally listen on port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS, both on the same IP address.

Comment: Right , but I can have two VIPs pointing to same host (IP address) and port . In my case both https(443) and http (80) vip are pointing to same ip address and same port and that's why I am unable to determine if request is coming from which protocol .

Comment: In order to process an HTTPS request you need to do the SSL session initiation when you receive the request. I didn't think you could do that on the same port as HTTP - I thought it needed immediate action from the server before you know the client's intentions. How are you handling that?

Comment: Well, you can call "port" a combination of ip address and port, in which case you still know what ip address and port combination the request comes to, either returned from `accept()` call or by having two distinct sockets for both listeners. Though it is quite weird idea to set up https on port 80 (or http on port 443).

Answer (score 3):

Which port you're listening to? 
By default HTTPS URLs begin with "https://" and use port 443 by default, where HTTP URLs begin with "http://" and use port 80 by default.

There are other questions like how you're managing certificates to serve secure connections?

This article might be helpful - http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/secureinternet/

Comment: the problem is both HTTP and HTTP server are listening on same port i.e both VIPS are pointing to same port ?

Comment: I doubt whether It's possible to have http and https on the same port, then how you will distinguish between the language to speak?

If you use CONNECT method, you can convert the request connection to a transparent TCP/IP tunnel, usually to facilitate SSL-encrypted communication (HTTPS) through an unencrypted HTTP proxy. (See Wikipedia)
An interesting thread I found in Serverfault - http://serverfault.com/questions/47876/handling-http-and-https-requests-using-a-single-port-with-nginx